# Maven Source Plugin - How do I generate the source jar for ONLY the classes I want included

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Currently, the project I am working on has all of the code for the web service in a single and is creating a war and a jar file.

The Jar file only contains the bare minimum of classes shared by other projects.
I don't have the option to split the shared classes out into a separate core project at this time. (Though I would prefer that)

I'm trying to put only the necessary java files in the source jar:

```
Common_Model-1.1.2.jar  
Common_Model-1.1.2.jar-sources
```

I have something like this in my POM:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>gov/app/api/common/models/**</include>
            <include>gov/app/api/intra/models/**</include>
            <include>gov/app/api/models/**</include>
          </includes>
          <finalName>Common_Model-1.1.2</finalName>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>gov/app/api/common/models/**</include>
            <include>gov/app/api/intra/models/**</include>
            <include>gov/app/api/models/**</include>
          </includes>
          <finalName>Common_Model-1.1.2</finalName>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

While this does create the sources jar, it ignores the includes configuration and adds all of the .java files from the entire project.

I've also tried using `<excludes>`, but that too is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in my project:

```
<include>com/sandbox/**/Permutations*</include>
```

And the resulting Common_Model-1.1.2-sources.jar only had this one file in it named Permutations.java  When I tried

```
<include>com/sandbox/Permutations*</include>
<include>com/sandbox/Sandbox*</include>
```

The jar had only those two files.  So what you've got should work.  I suspect your patterns are too broad.

Comment: I'm using the same patterns in the maven-jar-plugin. It works there but not in the maven-source-plugin.

Comment: I've also tried being more specific and using the path relative to the Project folder to no avail.